# Magento 2 : Coupon codes - auto generate

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

We already have a rule with 500 coupon codes auto-generated which are due for expiry in a few days.  If we generate a new set of auto-generated codes with a new start and finish date on the same rule I wanted to check that the old codes will not be affected and that they will remain in place.

> Question : Will it affect the existing rule when generating coupons in an existing rule?

Any ideas would be appreciated!